Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n + n \cos(x)}{n + x^2} \, dx$
I'm trying to solve $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n + n \cos(x)}{n + x^2} \, dx$$ and I do believe I have the right answer, however I do not know how to motivate the use of the Dominated Convergence Theorem (or if the criteria is even fulfilled).
My solution:
I split the the limit integral into two terms,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n + n \cos(x)}{n + x^2} \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\int_{0}^{1} (\frac{x^n}{n+x^2} + \frac{n \cos(x)}{n+x^2}) \, dx) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \, dx + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos(x)}{1+\frac{x^2}{n}} \, dx) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \, dx + \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos(x)}{1+\frac{x^2}{n}} \, dx.$
Since $0 = 0^n \leq x^n \leq 1^n = 1$ where $x \in [0,1] \implies$
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \, dx < \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{n} \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{1} \, dx = 0\int_{0}^{1} \, dx = 0.$
Applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem to the second term:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos(x)}{1+\frac{x^2}{n}} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} \cos(x) \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{n}} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} \cos(x) \frac{1}{1+0} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} \cos(x) \, dx = (\sin(1) + C) - (\sin(0) + C) = \sin(1).$
Therefore, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n + n \cos(x)}{n + x^2} \, dx = \sin(1).$
Is my solution correct? Is the simplification on the first term valid? How do I motivate the usage of the Dominated Convergence Theorem on the second term?
Thank you.

Everything looks fine. A dominating integrable function for the second term is the constant $1$

Instead of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} , dx < \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{n} , dx = ...= 0$ there should be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} , dx \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{n} , dx = ...= 0$. Here we have $\le$ instead of $<$.

The solution is almost correct.
Instead of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \, dx < \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{n} \, dx = ...= 0$ there should be $0 \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \, dx \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{n} \, dx = ...= 0$. Here we have $\le$ instead of $<$.
One more time:
for any $x \in [0,1]$ we have:
$$0 \le x \le 1 \implies$$
$$0 = 0^n \leq x^n \leq 1^n = 1 \implies $$
$$0 = \frac{0}{n+x^2} \le \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \le \frac{1}{n+x^2}  \le  \frac{1}{n+0} =\frac{1}{n} \implies $$
$$0 \le \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \le \frac{1}n \implies $$
$$\int_{0}^{1} 0 dx \le  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \le \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}n dx$$ and hence
$0 \le  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} dx \le \frac{1}n$. Applying sandwich theorem we get
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \, dx = 0$.
Conditions of dominated convergence theorem are fulfilled because $|\frac{cos(x)}{1+\frac{x^2}n}| =\frac{|cos(x)|}{1+\frac{x^2}n} \le |cos(x)| \le 1$ and because $\int_{0}^{1} 1 dx < \infty$.
Addition:
Statement 1:
If $x \in [0,1]$ then $\frac{0}{n+x^2} \le \frac{x^n}{n+x^2}$.
Statement 2:
If $x \in [0,1]$ then $\frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \le \frac{1}{n+x^2} $.
Statement 3:
If $x \in [0,1]$ then $\frac{1}{n+x^2} \le \frac{1}{n+0}$.
If $A \le B$ and $B \le C$ then $A \le C$. It follows from Statement 2 and Statement 3 that $ \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \le \frac{1}{n+0}$.
So we proved
Statement 4: If $x \in [0,1]$ then $ \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \le \frac{1}{n+0}$.
It follows from Statement 1 and Statement 4 that if $x \in [0,1]$ then $\frac{0}{n+x^2} \le \frac{x^n}{n+x^2} \le \frac{1}{n+0}$.

Applying the sandwich theorem is much better, thanks. However I thought about the inequality sign and I am wondering under which circumstance we have that $\frac{x^n}{n+x} = \frac{1}{n}$.

@KarlJohan we don't need to solve the equation $\frac{x^n}{n+x} = \frac1n$. I made my answer more detailed. Is everything clear now?

Yes I follow your inequalities. Still though, now you have the in the nominator $x=1$ and in the denominator $x=0$, but $x$ should only be able to have one value at a time and therefore I had the strict lesser inequality.
I cannot solve for $x$ the equation $\frac{x^n}{n+x^2} = \frac{1}{n}$, instead for all values that I have tried $\frac{x^n}{n+x^2}$ is always less than $\frac{1}{n}$.
Does that make sense?

@KarlJohan I made one more addition. Do you agree with statements 1,2,3? If yes, do you agree with statement 4?

Too complicated but for the pleasure of working an interesting integral.
You have done a nice work and your result is very correct.
In fact, you can obtain the exact solution. Consider, as you did, the first integral
$$I_1=\int_0^1  \frac{x^n}{n+x^2}\,dx=n^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\int_0^{\frac 1 {\sqrt n}}\frac{t^n}{1+t^2}\,dt$$
The antiderivative is known and, in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function,
$$I_1=\frac 1{n(n+1)}\,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+3}{2} ;-\frac{1}{n}\right)\color{red}{\sim \frac 1{n^2}}$$
Now,
$$I_2=\int_0^1 \frac{n \cos (x)}{n+x^2}\,dx=\frac{i \sqrt{n}}{2}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\cos(x)}{x+i \sqrt{n}}-\frac{\cos(x)}{x-i
   \sqrt{n}}\right)\,dx$$
Use the two obvious changes of variable, expand the cosine to face the usual sine and cosine integrals. Making the story short
$$I_2=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}(A-B)$$ where
$$A=\big(i\, \text{Ci}\left(1+i
   \sqrt{n}\right)-i \,\text{Ci}\left(1-i\sqrt{n}\right)+\pi \big) \cosh\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$$
$$B=\big(\text{Si}\left(1+i\sqrt{n}\right)+\text{Si}\left(1-i\sqrt{n}\right)\big) \sinh\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$$
Notice that $n$ does not need to be an integer (it just needs to be positive).
Computing exactly $(I_1+I_2)$ for a few values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I_1+I_2 \\
 1 & 1.029507 \\
 2 & 0.876459 \\
 3 & 0.842324 \\
 4 & 0.831321 \\
 5 & 0.827354 \\
 6 & 0.826030 \\
 7 & 0.825818 \\
 8 & 0.826100 \\
 9 & 0.826600 \\
 10 & 0.827187 \\
 11 & 0.827796 \\
 12 & 0.828397 \\
 13 & 0.828973 \\
 14 & 0.829517 \\
 15 & 0.830028 \\
 16 & 0.830506 \\
 17 & 0.830951 \\
 18 & 0.831366 \\
 19 & 0.831752 \\
 20 & 0.832113 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
showing a very slow convergence to something looking like $\sin(1)$ (one of the possible candidates given by an inverse symbolic calculator).
Edit
Computing for $n=5000$, the result is $\color{red}{0.8414}23$
My question is : why is there a minimum value of the integral for $n=6.803$ ?

The minimum is for $n=6.802906015728910217422162667\cdots$
